# Extended Cursor Movement in terminal emulator (CHA and others)

Tags: term, cursor, ansi-term

Is there a way to get the Emacs terminal emulator to support cursor movement escape sequences beyond its vt100 features? A specific example is CHA (Cursor-Character-Absolute), e.g. `ESC[0G` should move the cursor to column 0. CHA and a few other sequences were added as part of ISO-6429 (ECMA-48).

Try this rudimentary test in eterm and another terminal emulator:

```
printf "hello\033[0Gworld\n"
```

In eterm (`M-x term` or `M-x multi-term`) you will see:

```
helloworld
```

In Terminal.app I see:

```
world
```

For a full featured test check out [vttest](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/) (`brew install test` for me).

Comment: `ansi-color.el` adds support for ECMA-48 color escape sequences, but is only for Emacs shell as it relies on comint: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ansi-color.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't look that it's possible without some hacking.  The function `term-handle-ansi-escape` in `term.el` doesn't have a case for `ESC [ G`.

Comment: Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3):

Given the pointer to `term-handle-ansi-escape` by @jch I was able to add support for CHA as follows:

```
(defun toolbear:term-handle-more-ansi-escapes (proc char)
  "Handle additional ansi escapes."
  (cond
   ;; \E[nG - Cursor Horizontal Absolute, e.g. move cursor to column n
   ((eq char ?G)
    (let ((col (min term-width (max 0 term-terminal-parameter))))
      (term-move-columns (- col (term-current-column)))))
   (t)))
(advice-add 'term-handle-ansi-escape :before #'toolbear:term-handle-more-ansi-escapes)
```

Comment: I believe the current code in emacs 27.2 is wrong; it should move to the leftmost column when the parameter is 1, but it only goes to the second column.  Check the behaviour of echo -e "abc\033[1Gabc" ; in an emacs ansi-term it prints aabc, not just abc, because it doesn't go back far enough.